# Why is list being copied in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, memory, dataframe

I've been trying to improve my R programming skills recently by reading about and experimenting with memory usage in R. I was recently trying to recreate an example in Hadley's "Advanced R," but got different results. At the bottom of [this page](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) Hadley sets up the following example:

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100 * 1e4), ncol = 100))
medians <- vapply(x, median, numeric(1))
```

And then demonstrates the difference between primitive and non-primitives by showing that

```
for(i in 1:5) {
  x[, i] <- x[, i] - medians[i]
  print(c(address(x), refs(x)))
}
```

makes a copy every time the loop runs (since x is a data frame). While

```
y <- as.list(x)

for(i in 1:5) {
  y[[i]] <- y[[i]] - medians[i]
  print(c(address(y), refs(y)))
}
```

modifies y in place (since y has been transformed to a list, which is a primitive object). However, when I recreated this code I found that in both instances copies are made:

```
> x <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100 * 1e4), ncol = 100))
> medians <- vapply(x, median, numeric(1))
> 
> for(i in 1:5) {
+   x[, i] <- x[, i] - medians[i]
+   print(c(address(x), refs(x)))
+ }
[1] "0x10e4e6770" "2"          
[1] "0x10e46c420" "2"          
[1] "0x121110180" "2"          
[1] "0x11c2c26d0" "2"          
[1] "0x121151db0" "2"  


> x <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100 * 1e4), ncol = 100))
> medians <- vapply(x, median, numeric(1))
> y <- as.list(x)
> 
> for(i in 1:5) {
+   y[[i]] <- y[[i]] - medians[i]
+   print(c(address(y), refs(y)))
+ }
[1] "0x132aea2b0" "2"          
[1] "0x1211839e0" "2"          
[1] "0x11c237ea0" "2"          
[1] "0x121169a80" "2"          
[1] "0x10993f460" "2"
```

It appears Hadley is using at least R 3.1.0 in his example whereas I'm using R 3.1.2 (on a Mac). However, everything I've read suggests R is getting better with memory management over time, whereas the above result suggests it's getting worse. Although I'm likely doing something foolish or misunderstanding something essential. Can anyone inculcate me as to why my reproduction does not have the same memory efficiency as Hadley's example?

Comment: Are you using RStudio? I found this note: "Note that if you’re using RStudio, refs() will always return 2: the environment browser makes a reference to every object you create on the command line." at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification

Comment: I also saw that note, but: (1) I assume Hadley is also using RStudio in this example since he's RStudio's Chief Scientist, (2) while refs may be artificially inflated I don't believe the address should be changing, (3) I recreated the example in R proper and ran into the same issue.

Comment: Beats me. Tried under Linux to see if maybe this was OS-related but got the same results as in Win7.

Comment: Can anyone explain why the hex memory address increases while iterating over the data frame but decreases while iterating over the list?

Comment: Which result are you getting, mine or Hadley's?

Comment: Also the spread in memory used for iterating over the list is **much** less than for the data frame.  @JJMcCammon I am referring to your output.

Comment: @JJ I have the same result as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As currently implemented in the CRAN version of pryr and when run in current R the address() function will increase the number of references of its argument to 2. Once that happens the object has to be duplicated for replacement calls. The refs() function implementation avoids adding a reference, so if you just print refs(y) you will see that it remain at 1 and there will be no duplication.

Comment: You can also see there's no duplication if you simply use `tracemem`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help Luke and Joshua!

Answer (score 0):

It is not the direct answer of your problem, but I think that your script might mislead you. The change of the address of the list and data.frame does not imply that the copy of all the data.

`list` and `data.frame` in R are vector of R objects. In your script, R should only copy the replaced R objects and hence the address of the list is changed.

For example:

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100 * 1e4), ncol = 100))
medians <- vapply(x, median, numeric(1))

for(i in 1:5) {
  print(sprintf("===%d===", i))
  for(j in 1:5) print(sprintf("%s(%d)", address(x[[j]]), j))
  x[, i] <- x[, i] - medians[i]
  print(c(address(x), refs(x)))
  for(j in 1:5) print(sprintf("%s(%d)", address(x[[j]]), j))
}

y <- as.list(x)

for(i in 1:5) {
  print(sprintf("===%d===", i))
  for(j in 1:5) print(sprintf("%s(%d)", address(y[[j]]), j))
  y[[i]] <- y[[i]] - medians[i]
  for(j in 1:5) print(sprintf("%s(%d)", address(y[[j]]), j))
}
```

You should see that there are only 1 address changed in each iteration. The assignment `<-` only copies the data of the corresponding R object, which is `x[[i]]` and `y[[i]]`. The 4 left objects are not copied.